# Error when trying to get full_text for a Tweet using Tweepy and Python

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to use Tweepy and streaming to track Tweets in real time. I am using the following which works fine:

```
import tweepy
import configparser
import sys

#read configs                                                                                              
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

api_key = config['twitter']['api_key']
api_key_secret = config['twitter']['api_key_secret']

access_token = config['twitter']['access_token']
access_token_secret = config['twitter']['access_token_secret']


class StreamCollector(tweepy.Stream):

    def on_status(self, status):
        if not hasattr(status, 'retweeted_status') and status.in_reply_to_screen_name == None and status.i\
s_quote_status == False:
            if status.author.followers_count > 100000:
                print('Twitter Handle: @'+status.author.screen_name)
                print('Followers:',status.author.followers_count)
                print('Tweet:',status.text)
                print('\n')
        #print(status.user.screen_name.encode('UTF-8'))                                                    


stream = StreamCollector(api_key,api_key_secret,access_token, access_token_secret)
stream.filter(track=["table"])
```

However, I want to produce the **untruncated** Tweet. I tried substituting `status.text` for `status.full_text` but I got the error:

`AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'full_text'`

My version of Tweepy is 4.5.0 and Python is 3.9.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tweepy.API` has a `compatibility mode` and `extended mode`.  The `extended mode` should allow you to get the full text of the Tweet.

ref: [Extended Tweets](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/2538956b62c6282e35d6482d151b2dd3cc071544/docs/extended_tweets.rst)

Here is the code with the `extended mode` call.

```
import sys
import tweepy
import configparser

#read configs                                                                                              
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

api_key = config['twitter']['api_key']
api_key_secret = config['twitter']['api_key_secret']

access_token = config['twitter']['access_token']
access_token_secret = config['twitter']['access_token_secret']


class StreamCollector(tweepy.Stream):

    def on_status(self, status):
        if not hasattr(status, 'retweeted_status'):
            if status.in_reply_to_screen_name is None and status.is_quote_status is False:
                if status.author.followers_count > 100000:
                    print(f'Twitter Handle: @{status.author.screen_name}')
                    print(f'Followers: {status.author.followers_count}')

                    if 'extended_tweet' in status._json:
                        full_text = status._json['extended_tweet']['full_text']
                        print(f'Tweet: {full_text}')
                    elif 'extended_tweet' not in status._json:
                        print(f'Tweet: {status.text}')

                    print('\n')
                                                          

stream = StreamCollector(api_key,api_key_secret,access_token, access_token_secret)
stream.filter(track=["table"])
```

Comment: When I do this I get the error `AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'extended_tweet'`. But I do see this example in https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/extended_tweets.html so perhaps this is a version issue?

Comment: What version of `tweepy` are you using?

Comment: The version is 4.5.0.

Comment: Thanks for the version info.  I'm looking into the error message.  I'm also trying to get you a working code example that doesn't throw an error.

Comment: @user1551817 The documentation for `tweepy` 4.5.0 has no solid example(s) for tweepy.Stream.

Comment: @user1551817 I updated the code after looking through `tweepy` document. Please let me know if this answer works for you.

Comment: @user1551817 I'm glad that this worked. It was pain searching for something that worked.  I was shocked that 'tweepy` documentation was thin on this subject.  Those 50 bounty points linked to this question will be missed ;-}

Answer (score -1):

Streaming is covered in [Tweepy's documentation on extended Tweets](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.0/extended_tweets.html):

> By default, the Status objects from streams may contain an `extended_tweet` attribute representing the equivalent field in the raw data/payload for the Tweet. This attribute/field will only exist for extended Tweets, containing a dictionary of sub-fields. The `full_text` sub-field/key of this dictionary will contain the full, untruncated text of the Tweet